# X axis domain line overlapping with d3 bar stroke

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I should have a white border when I select any bar in my d3 bar chart. So here the border is achieved using stroke, but the bottom border is getting hidden under the x domain line.

```
// container size
var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 30},
width = 400,
height = 300;

var data = [
{"month":"DEC","setup":{"count":26,"id":1,"label":"Set Up","year":"2016","graphType":"setup"}},
{"month":"JAN","setup":{"count":30,"id":1,"label":"Set Up","year":"2017","graphType":"setup"}},
{"month":"FEB","setup":{"count":30,"id":1,"label":"Set Up","year":"2017","graphType":"setup"}}];

var name = 'dashboard';

// x scale
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
.rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.2);

// set x and y scales
xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.month; }));

// x axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(xScale)
.orient('bottom')
.outerTickSize(0);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {  
    return d.setup.count;
})])
.range([height, 0]);

var ticks = yScale.ticks(),
lastTick = ticks[ticks.length-1];    
var newLastTick = lastTick + (ticks[1] - ticks[0]);  
if (lastTick < yScale.domain()[1]){
    ticks.push(lastTick + (ticks[1] - ticks[0]));
}

// adjust domain for further value
yScale.domain([yScale.domain()[0], newLastTick]);

// y axis
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(yScale)
.orient('left')
.tickSize(-width, 0, 0) 
.tickFormat(d3.format('d'))
.tickValues(ticks);


// create svg container
var svg = d3.select('#chart')
.append('svg')
.attr('class','d3-setup-barchart')
.attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append('g')
.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');
//.on('mouseout', tip.hide);        

// apply tooltip
//svg.call(tip);

// Horizontal grid (y axis gridline)
svg.append('g')         
.attr('class', 'grid horizontal')
.call(d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(yScale)
      .orient('left')
      .tickSize(-width, 0, 0) 
      .tickFormat('')
      .tickValues(ticks)
      );

// create bars
var bars = svg.selectAll('.bar')
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('g');

bars.append('rect')
.attr('class', function(d,i) {
    return 'bar';
})
.attr('id', function(d, i) {
    return name+'-bar-'+i;
})
.attr('x', function(d) { return xScale(d.month); })
.attr('width', xScale.rangeBand())
.attr('y', function(d) { return yScale(d.setup.count); })
.attr('height', function(d) { return height - yScale(d.setup.count); })
.on('click', function(d, i) {
    d3.select(this.nextSibling)
    .classed('label-text selected', true);
    d3.select(this)
    .classed('bar selected', true);  
    d3.select('#'+name+'-axis-text-'+i)
    .classed('axis-text selected', true);
});
//.on('mouseover', tip.show)
//.on('mouseout', tip.hide);

// apply text at the top
bars.append('text')
.attr('class',function(d,i) {
    return 'label-text';
})
.attr('x', function(d) { return xScale(d.month) + (xScale.rangeBand()/2) - 10; })
.attr('y', function(d) { return yScale(d.setup.count) + 2 ; })
.attr('transform', function() { return 'translate(10, -10)'; })
.text(function(d) { return d.setup.count; });

// draw x axis
svg.append('g')
.attr('id', name+'-x-axis')
.attr('class', 'x axis')
.attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
.call(xAxis);

// apply class & id to x-axis texts
d3.select('#'+name+'-x-axis')
.selectAll('text')
.attr('class', function(d,i) {
    return 'axis-text';
})
.attr('id', function(d,i) { return name+'-axis-text-' + i; });

// draw y axis
svg.append('g')
.attr('class', 'y axis')
.call(yAxis)
.append('text')
.attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
.attr('y', 6)
.attr('dy', '.71em')
.style('text-anchor', 'end');

// remove 0 in y axis
svg.select('.y')
.selectAll('.tick')
.filter(function (d) { 
    return d === 0 || d % 1 !== 0;     
}).remove();

svg
.select('.horizontal')
.selectAll('.tick')
.filter(function (d) { 
    return d === 0 || d % 1 !== 0;     
}).remove();
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/betasquirrel/1wf1jts6/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a SVG, whoever is painted last stays on top.

That being said, simply append your x axis...

```
svg.append('g')
   .attr('id', name + '-x-axis')
   .attr('class', 'x axis')
   .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
   .call(xAxis);
```

... **before** the bars:

```
var bars = svg.selectAll('.bar')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('g');
```

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5bnzt6nb/